# Remove rows of a data frame, based on the connection between multiple columns

Tags: r

Considering the following data frame:

```
# input 
a <- data.frame(
  X1=c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b"),
  X2=c(2,4,6,2,4,7,9,5,4,7,3,5,8,4,3,5,7,6,3,5),
  X3=c(5,6,1,4,7,5,5,4,4,2,5,4,5,2,4,7,3,5,3,7)
)
```

How can I remove any row, which is smaller in terms of both variable 2 and variable 3 than another row, where the two rows are of the same factor level (variable 1)?

E.G.

```
a[1,1]==a[2,1] and
a[1,2]<a[2,2] and 
a[1,3]<a[2,3] then a[1,] should be removed.

# output 

a <- data.frame( X1=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"), 
                 X2=c(4,4,7,9,8,5,6,5), 
                 X3=c(6,7,5,5,5,7,5,7) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `isRemoved` will give `TRUE` or `FALSE` given the condition for each row `i`:

```
isRemoved = function(i, a) {
  out = logical(nrow(a))
  for(j in 1:nrow(a)) {
    out[j] = a[i,1]==a[j,1] & a[i,2]<a[j,2] & a[i,3]<a[j,3]
  }
  out = any(out)
  return(out)
}
```

then, you can apply that to all rows:

```
remove = sapply(1:nrow(a), isRemoved, a=a)
```

and keep the row you want:

```
a.new = a[!remove, ]

a.new 

   X1 X2 X3
2   a  4  6
5   a  4  7
6   a  7  5
7   a  9  5
13  b  8  5
16  b  5  7
18  b  6  5
20  b  5  7
```

Answer (score 3):

If speed is not your main concern, this is quite readable in my opinion:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(a, "X1", function(x) {
  n <- seq_len(nrow(x))
  m <- outer(n, n, Vectorize(function(i,j) all(x[i, 2:3] < x[j, 2:3])))
  i <- rowSums(m) > 0L
  return(x[!i, ])
})
```

where `m` is a matrix of `TRUE` and `FALSE` telling if row `i` is dominated by row `j`, for all combinations of `i` and `j`.